# Is there a way to remove file with substitutions in name in linux?

Tags: linux

Let's say I have directory with files: log[1-3], log1, log2, log3. I want to type a command and remove file log[1-3]. How it can be done?.

Yes I know, that I can type `rm -i log*` and then choose file that I wanted to remove, but it is not appropriate for me, because in this directory can be many files begins with log.

So, i need a way to do this with just one command.

Comment: Why can't you use `log*`?

Comment: Take a look at [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)

Comment: does [this](https://superuser.com/a/392878/445612) answer your question?

Comment: You want to remove __one__ file named _literally_ `log[1-3]` , or do you want to remove three files `log1` `log2` and `log3`? If the former, so `rm 'log[1-3]'`, if the latter, why not `rm log[1-3]`?

Answer (score 0):

I found way to do this. You just need to type `rm 'log[1-3]'`. With a single quotes

Thank you CamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two ways to do this:

```
rm log\[1-3\]
rm 'log[1-3]'
```

`rm log\[1-3\]` is a result of `rm log` <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd>
`rm 'log[1-3]'` is a result of `ls -ltra`.